# Strange behaviour with `np.floor()` and float division

Tags: python, numpy

What's going on here?

```
In [86]:  np.floor(10.0 * .91)
Out[86]:  9.0

In [87]:  np.floor(10.0 * .91)/10.0
Out[87]:  0.90000000000000002
```

Why not `0.9`?

### Edit:

I want to do something like this:

```
#create 2d bins
bins = {}
for x in np.arange(-1,1, 0.1):
    for y in np.arange(-1,1, 0.1):
        bins[(x,y)] = 0

#count number of occurences in each bin
for x,y in np.random.randn(10,2):
    rounded = (np.floor(10.0 * x)/10.0, np.floor(10.0 * y)/10.0)
    bins[(x,y)] += 1   # I get an error here
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `floor`.  `np.int32(9)/10` gives the same result.

Comment: "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with `np.floor`.  Take a look at `np.float64(0.9)`.  Then read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that numpy has a different algorithm for converting `float64` to string compared to Python's `float`.

When the strings 0.90000000000000002 and 0.9 are parsed as float64, they end up having the same bit pattern.

You can confirm that `np.floor(10.0 * .91)/10.0 == 0.9` yields `True`.

The root problem here is, when converting a float to a string, how many decimal places should be given? Some implementations use the minimum number of digits such that parsing the string to the closest float value will yield the same value. Some implementations will give extra digits for safety.

Because ultimately, float("0.9") is actually exactly equal to 0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625. So in a sense, both answers are right.

---

Q&A second part: You could spend time figuring out how floating point works, or you can use integer buckets for your dictionary.

In other words, instead of having keys like `-1.0, -0.9, -0.8, ..., 0.9`, instead have the keys `-10, -9, -8, ..., 9`. It should prevent a lot of problems down the road.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question because even though I understand your answer, I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Okay, I addressed the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The result you got *is* 0.9, or at least as close to 0.9 as a double-precision floating point number can get:

```
>>> numpy.float64(0.9)
0.90000000000000002
```

0.9 can't be represented exactly in a finite binary fraction number, so it has to be approximated.

Python's built-in floating-point type `float` tries to hide the problem from you by always trying to find the shortest decimal representation that would be rounded to a given floating-point number.  That's why you get

```
>>> 0.9
0.9
```

in current versions of Python.  Earlier versions (I think up to 2.6) would show you the same rounded value you got for Numpy's floating-point data type.

Comment: But wait: `math.floor()` on the questioner's same code behaves differently, and prints 0.9

Comment: @NayukiMinase: It's due to the different `__repr__()` implementations on Python's built-in `float` type and `numpy.float64`.  I expanded my answer.